Font and Rendering issue in Docx4j docx to pdf conversion using java
I'm converting docx to pdf using docx4j library in java. after converting to pdf font styles are missing and table and text rendering is not proper. i have checked the font substitution in word but it's proper only there is no issue. is there any way to handle these issues while converting to pdf.
Below is my code
public void convertToPdf(String srcPath, String destPath) {
    try {
      Mapper fontMapper = new BestMatchingMapper();
      InputStream templateInputStream = new FileInputStream(srcPath);
      WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(templateInputStream);
      wordMLPackage.setFontMapper(fontMapper);
      FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(destPath);
      Docx4J.toPDF(wordMLPackage, os);
      System.out.println("Successfully converted to pdf");
      os.flush();
      os.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

I'm using docx4j version
implementation 'org.docx4j:docx4j:11.4.11'

Thanks in advance for the help
